# 12.10 won't allow Windows partition to boot

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, partitioning

I upgraded to 12.04.2 and my windows partition wouldn't boot any more. I tried 12.10 and I still have the same problem.

Here is the url generated when Boot Repair attempted fixing the issue.  It seems the boot location is different from what it should be. I don't know how to fix it.

- http://paste.ubuntu.com/5565425

Please help if you know the solution.

Comment: that link didn't work for me.

Comment: Link didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 2):

Copy and paste the following command into a terminal window :

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Enter your password when asked.

These things happen all the time

Comment: http:/paste.ubuntu.com/5565425 is the correct url

Comment: I updated grub2 and it still didn't help.

Comment: so two thing just to be sure, first, do you still have your windows? you can check in Ubuntu and see if your windows folder and other stuff are located in sda4. the second thing, what happens at boot time? you definitely see windows in your boot menu, what happens when you choose that option?

Comment: The windows partition still exists. I see it after ubuntu boots. When the computer starts it goes directly to Ubuntu. It doesn't show any options screen, just goes straight to loading ubuntu.

Comment: so when you enter `sudo update-grub2` it shows the operating systems it finds. does that mean it doesn't find it at all? in this case I think your windows installation is broken. you have to insert windows DVD and boot up and select repair, then start the startup repair. after that you have to boot with a Ubuntu live CD and then run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: you can also try the Boot-Repair before the windows startup repair but I suspect it helps you.

Comment: It finds windows and mentions it, but windows still isn't given an opportunity to open at boot.

Comment: ok, so can you try [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer). Then open it and go to `General Settings -> Advanced Settings` now check the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` and see if it's non-zero. sorry that it takes lot's of effort to fix such problems, but I guess you are already familiar with the linux world :)

Comment: [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664134) is a good walkthrough on that.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall grub2 (Does anyone have a link to a guide?)
if that didn't hewlp, try Boot-repair:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Need more help? tell me (: